# Making one input tag required dependant on another

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that displays a list items in a table like format with the first column being a check-box and the last column being a numeric field where an estimate can be entered. I am looking for a way to make the the check-box ( the first input tag) required if and only if an amount has been entered so that someone cannot submit the form if an amount is not entered but its corresponding check-box is not checked. Despite days of contemplating a solution I cannot seem to be able to find a way. I Below is what I have so far.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form role="form" action="../../openitems" method="POST">
        <h3 class="text-center">Select line-items and enter estimate</h3>
        <div class="well" style="max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
      <ul class="list-group fancy-list-items">    <!-- <ul class="list-group checked-list-box"> -->   
        <table style="width:100%">
        <% FOREACH ID IN Chlngs.keys.sort %>
        <tr class="list-group-item">
        <td width="5"> <input type="checkbox" name="<% Chlngs.$ID.NAME %>"></td>
        <td width="90"><% Chlngs.$ID.PSNAME %></td> 
        <td width="80"><% Chlngs.$ID.ANAME %></td>
        <td width="48"><% Chlngs.$ID.SSN %></td> 
        <td width="45"><% Chlngs.$ID.YEAR %></td>
        <td width="250"><% Chlngs.$ID.CHNAME %></td>
        <td width="520"><% Chlngs.$ID.DESCRIP %></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="<% Chlngs.$ID.ID %>" placeholder="Dollar Amount" min="1" max="1000"></td>
          </tr>
          <% END %>
        </table>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"></div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```